# PowerAMC do simple action with script

Tags: xml, vbscript, xsd, powerdesigner

I'm a beginner in **powerAMC**.
**PowerAMC** offer to see and save a **XSD** file of your **Model** component :

[image: Native fonction of PowerAMC]

I need to get automatically that **XSD** content for all **models** in the project. So I need to do it by **script**.

I can't find a way to get that content (**XSD** of the picture).
Anybody no a way ? By calling a PowerAmc Fonction ? Get a specific property of the **model** ? another way ?

Thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that would the `Preview` (string) property, available for all `NamedObject`.

Comment: Perfect ! Sorry for my question whose was very simply in fact.
Thx pascal !!